How to connect a second monitor on linux ubuntu 24.04.01
First of all, I'm new to this operating system.
I bought a notebook that already came with Ubuntu installed, I decided not to switch to Windows because they say that Linux is used a lot for programming and I want to work with that in the future, so I want to familiarize myself with the system.
Returning to the question: After a while, I updated the system (it came in version 20.04) because it had some bugs (but it was possible to connect the external monitor), such as crashes and the fact that I couldn't use the graphics tablet, which is the main way I have to work, on both monitors, it only worked on the native one)
Then I went to version 22.0: in it I could still mirror/join the screens, as in version 20.04, but I faced a bug where the mouse/touchpad/pen tablet click simply did not work in the operating system, I had to navigate only through the tab or keyboard commands. Soon after I installed version 24.04.01, and I still have the problem: The external monitor is not even recognized, in the xrandr command only data from the notebook monitor appears.
When researching I discovered that the problem is probably the different refresh rate of the monitors, and that an app called "compizconfig" is capable of solving this, however, as I said, the external monitor is simply not recognized, so I can't make changes /manipulations with the program.
I would like to know if there is a stable Ubuntu version that doesn't cause me so much headache, I can even change distro or operating system, but, as I said, I want to familiarize myself with Linux.

Please add requested information to your original posting: Model notebook, How you login (at password prompt, select Wayland (the default for ubuntu) or xorg)? Joining displays works better under xorg, Wayland mirror seems to work just fine for me. Ensure you select the xorg choice.
